URL Content Redirection in Azure Virtual Desktop
Does Azure Virtual Desktop have an equivalent of Horizon's URL Content Redirection / can that same behaviour be acheived in some way?
Specifically, we have an application hosted in AVD which generates a URI (with a querystring generated by the application based on data selected in the app, to improve the user experience of working across the two systems).  That URI currently gets openned in the browser on the VDI server, which opens a web app; but the web app generates complex visualisations, so requires a graphics card to be performant.  Enabling graphics cards on the VDI server significantly increases the costs; whilst our users' client devices already have an appropriate spec to comfortably handle this web app.
We'd like the request to open the browser to push a signal back to the client device asking it to open the URI in its local browser, instead of using the browser in the VDI session, in order to avoid this issue.  If we can enable this behviour for specific sites/domains, so much the better, but that's a nice to have; having the client browser act as the default browser for everything is good enough.
If we have to add code to our app so that the link clicks don't just use the default OS "open links using this app" behaviour but have custom logic to send an instruction back to the client, that's less ideal, but also acceptable.
Installing additional software on the VDI server & client to enable this functionality may also be acceptable (though only if the cost of this software & of the additional effort to distribute/manage it is less than that of upgrading the spec of our VDI servers).
Migrating off AVD in favour of other VDI offerings is not an option.
